# Display custom conversion error message with <rich:beanValidator />

Tags: jsf, richfaces, hibernate-validator

I'm using hibernate validators with JSF.
How can I set my conversion error messages? I am using them in the following way, but it didn't work:

```
<h:inputText id="input" value="#{myBean.number}" converterMessage="#{msgs.convertError}">
    <f:convertNumber />
    <rich:beanValidator />
    <rich:ajaxValidator event="onblur"/>
</h:inputText>
```

I can set custom validator messages in my bean like this:

```
@NotNull
@Min(value = 1, message="{greateThanOne}")
public long getNumber() {
    return number;
}
```

But what to do with conversion errors?

Comment: Do you mean conversion errors?  Then they will appear in your <h:message> area.

Comment: I forget to say that I have  <rich:message for="input"/>. And i want to change message that showed after conversation error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into Faces resource file (jsf-api.jar, javax/faces/Messages.properties).
Just define the following keys in your own resource file and configure it in faces-config.xml.

```
javax.faces.converter.NumberConverter.NUMBER={2}: ''{0}'' is not a number.
javax.faces.converter.NumberConverter.NUMBER_detail={2}: ''{0}'' is not a number. Example: {1}
```